# write xlsx with openxlsx package for large data frames that include utf-8 characters

Tags: r, excel

I am trying to write a fairly large data frame (more than 200 columns and more than 6000 rows) that includes Hebrew characters to excel using the openxlsx package through shiny.
For some reason when I download the file I get a corrupt excel file, when trying to open it i get a

> excel found unreadable content do you want to recover the contents of this workbook

and then:

> excel was able to open the file by repairing or removing the unreadable content

Once i open the file all the hebrew characters are gone!
Trying to reproduce this issue I found that if I try writing a smaller data frame for instance [100:100] it works the hebrew is there, but once i make my data frame larger it does not work.
[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bzhw9flL8QdsQTlVeGhTSXh4Yms/view?usp=sharing) is a link to the file I am using in the test code below 
and here is the code i am using:
 
 **server.R**

```
library(shiny)
    library(openxlsx)
    shinyServer(function(input, output) {
      datasetInput <- reactive({
      file_1 <- read.csv("../file1.txt", header=T, stringsAsFactors =F)   
      file1<-file_1[1:200,1:200] ##if i place here [100:100] it works fine!
      return(file1)
      })

  output$table <- renderTable({
    datasetInput()
  })

  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() { paste("download", "xlsx", sep='.') },
    content = function(file){
      fname <- paste(file,"xlsx",sep=".")
   wb <- createWorkbook()
   print(class(datasetInput()))
    addWorksheet(wb = wb, sheetName = "Sheet 1", gridLines = FALSE)
    writeDataTable(wb = wb, sheet = 1, x = datasetInput())
    saveWorkbook(wb, file, overwrite = TRUE)
    }
  )
})
```

**ui.R**

```
 shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
      headerPanel('Download Example'),
      sidebarPanel(
        downloadButton('downloadData', 'Download')
      ),
      mainPanel(
        tableOutput('table')
      )
    ))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the creator of this package Alexander Walker the issue was solved:
It appears the issue is due to an escape character in one of the strings "\b"

```
> x <- read.csv("file1.txt")
> x[150,44]
[1] ÷øéîéðåìåâéä áäúîçåú áîãò ôåøðæé - îåñîê    \b
```

The  fix is:

```
x <- read.csv("file1.txt", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
wb <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb, "Sheet 1")

is_character_col <- which(sapply(x, class) %in% "character")
for(i in is_character_col){
  x[[i]] <- gsub("\b", "", x[[i]], fixed = TRUE)
}

writeDataTable(wb, 1, x)
saveWorkbook(wb, "hopefully_fixed.xlsx")
```